# In react native, when shifting screens, the default screen also gets executed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I’ve declared a navigation structure with a default screen (initialRouteName) to be executed when the app launches, like so:

```
const App = () => {
    return (
        <AuthProvider>
            <NavigationContainer>
                <AppFlow.Navigator
                    initialRouteName={'ResolveAuth'}
                    screenOptions={{
                        headerShown: false
                    }}
                >
                    <AppFlow.Screen name='ResolveAuth' component={ResolveAuthScreen} />
                    <AppFlow.Screen name='Signup' component={SignupScreen} />
                    <AppFlow.Screen name='Signin' component={SigninScreen} />
                    <AppFlow.Screen
                        name='mainFlow'
                        component={mainFlowComponent}
                    />
                </AppFlow.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        </AuthProvider>
    );
};
```

ResolveAuthScreen figures out if the user was signed in before.

But, when I’m in the Signup screen, I should be able to shift to SigninScreen directly:

```
const SignupScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {

    return (
        <View>
            <Text >"Sign Up"</Text>
More code …

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Signin')}>
                <Text>Already have an account?. Sign in instead</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
};
```

It happens that when the user presses Signin, React Native is executing the ResolveAuthScreen first. I want to navigate directly to Signin without passing by ResolveAuthScreen first

Can it be done?

Rafael

Comment: What you meant by 'React Native is executing the ResolveAuthScreen first'? Are you saying that the ResolveAuthScreen is being displayed in between the navigation from SignupScreen to SigninScreen?

Comment: no, I just found out that it is a useEffect(...[something]) that remains somehow hanging waiting for the something to change, and whenit did, this useEffect (that's inside ResolveAuthScreen ) executed, making me believe that the entire ResolveAuthScreen  was being executed. So, I'm trying to solve it. Thank for responding